# A subset of unit square

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, contest-math

> A subset $\mathcal{S}$ of an unit square is equal to the sum of some
>   number of disjoint and congruent squares. The total area of these
>   squares is equal to $\frac{17}{50}$. Prove that one can find two
>   points in the subset $\mathcal{S}$ such that the distance between them
>   is equal to $\frac{1}{2003}$?

Frankly, where to start? I expect this to be sort of problem one can to using pigeonhole principle, but where to find it here? My idea was to consider that the subset is made of $n$ squares of size $a\times a$. Then we have that $na^2=\frac{17}{50}$, but what next?

Comment: Have you tried proof by contradiction? If we let $x=\frac{1}{2003}$, and if a side length $a$ satisfies $a\ge \frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}$, then the two points you're looking for are simply inside any square. So consider side lengths less than that, find how many squares you need to satisfy the area argument, and show that they must be packed in tight enough that they can't all be more than $x$ apart (think about drawing a line of distance $x/2$ around the squares and show intersection, maybe).

Comment: Something's gone wrong with your comment, but I appreciate the hint. Let me see if I can work it out.

Comment: Sorry, misplaced a \$ on my phone. It should be readable now!

Answer (score 1):

*Work in progress. This seems overly complicated but could provide a suitable route.*

---

The actual target distance given here, $\frac {1}{2003}$, is not important, provided it is smaller than the distance that would produce a border region of less than $1/50$th the unit square area (so any value less than say $\frac{1}{200}$ would be suitable for this proof). Consider such a distance $t$.

Firstly consider how small a single square must be to exclude having two points $t$ apart within its boundary. The distance across the diagonal of a square is $s\sqrt 2$, with $s$ as its side length. Then $s\sqrt 2 < t$ gives $s<\frac{t}{\sqrt 2}$. Thus we can consider squares below this dimension.

Now consider image of such a square displaced in all possible directions, creating a ring around the square . This is the area that other squares cannot overlap in order to avoid points being distance $t$ apart. For example there are non-overlapping images of the square directly out from all four sides and all four corners.

[image]

For the purposes of this proof consider the $6$ images of the square at corners of a regular hexagon:

[image]

This part of the overlap zone can be shared by $12$ other square, $6$ sharing only one square image and $6$ sharing two.